# closing element opened by toggle() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to close element opened by toggle() function when I click on any place in browser window. For example StackExchange link on this site. When I click on this link div appears, but if I click on any place in window, it disappears.

Comment: paste the `toggle()` functions.

Comment: @Wachburn Where is the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in this way:

```
$(function(){
  $('.yourelem, .targetDiv').click(function(ev){
    $('.targetDiv').slideDown('fast');
    ev.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(document).click(function(){
    $('.targetDiv').slideUp('fast');
  });
});
```

### [See the action in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ayuhol/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

HTML

```
<a id="show" href="#">show</a>
<div class="test" style="display: none;">
    hey
</div>
```

JS

```
$('a#show').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.test').toggle(); 
});

$('html').click(function() {
    $('.test').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on .blur function of jquery http://api.jquery.com/blur/

A quick example:

```
 $("#myelement").blur(function(){
    $(this).hide(); 
    //or
    $("#targetelement").hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make variable sel `true`, if we click on the `div`.

```
if(sel)
$(".stackExchange").slideDown(800);

else 
$(".stackExchange").slideUp(800);
```